# Relation between the limit of sum of function series and the limit of the functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let $I=[a,b]$ be a closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$

Let $h: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real function such that $\lim_{x \to x_0} h(x)=0$

Let $f_n(x)$ a sequence of real functions defined on $I$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:$
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0}f_n(x)=0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0}
\left|
\dfrac
{f_n(x)}
{h(x)}
\right|
=
L_n
\text{ and }
0<L_n<\infty
$$
and the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
|f_n(x)|
=
f(x)
$$
converges uniformly.
I would like to know if is it true that
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0}
\dfrac
{|f(x)|}
{|h(x)|}
<\infty
$$

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well :

$$ \lim_{x\to x_0}{|f(x)|\over|h(x)|} = \lim_{x\to x_0} {\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{|f_n(x)|\over |h(x)|}} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\lim_{x\to x_0}{|f_n(x)|\over |h(x)|}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}L_n$$

But since we only know $0<L_n<+\infty$ we can't conclude.

For example : $$\forall n,L_n = 2 \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}L_n = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2 = +\infty$$

But we could also have :

$$\forall n,L_n = {1\over n^2} \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}L_n = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{1\over n^2} < +\infty$$

EDIT : I don't have time left today but I think the key here is what I first missed : since $\sum_{1}^{+\infty}|f_n(x)|$ is uniform absolute convergent, you should be able to deduce that $L_n\to_{n\to\infty}0$ with a sufficient "speed" to conclude.

Comment: are you sure that you can take the limit after sum? we need uniform convergence to do it

Comment: @MateyMath yes we can.

Comment: if we can tell me why, because for me it's enough to solve my question, please